# Stripe webhooks - checking request from Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, webhooks, endpoint

I want to check if request on my endpoint is from Stripe.
I can do this, I can check this but the problem is - my code after try catch blocks is not triggering.

Even if I write all this console logs in try block AFTER I assing response from Promise to event variable.
All of my code AFTER event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret); is not working. Also I dont have any errors...

I want to send response 200 and continue with more complicated code on server but it stops working after checking req from stripe.

```
    pixelRouter.post("/payments", async (req, res) => {
  //Checking if request is from STRIPE
  const payload = req.body;
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"];
  const endpointSecret =
    "my secret endpoint here";
  let event;
  try {
    event = await stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(payload, sig, endpointSecret);
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`);
    console.log(err.message);
  }
  //********************************* */
  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":
      console.log("Code for checkout session completed");
      break;
    case "payment_intent.succeeded":
      console.log("Payment succeeeded");
      break;
    default:
      console.log("???");
  }
  console.log("ndkndnn");
  res.json({ success: true });
});
```

Comment: And you are saying that no error message is logged in your catch block?  Can you try putting a console.log(event) statement INSIDE the try block and see what is returned?

Comment: Yes, I have no errors at all!
Very strange... I try to console.log(event) in try but it's not console logged anything. It's like code is not working after stripe promise... I don't know why!

Comment: Ok, so I converted try catch on old ".then and catch".
Now error is catched.

Problem was that parsing req.body on json on every route and I must read raw req.body from Stripe.

So I fixed this. But then, I back to try catch block and I back to parsed json on every route and async await and try catch didn't catch any errors, this is weird.

Comment: Well for sure need to use the raw body, since it's part of the hash used to verify the event.  The rest sounds like some odd async/await behavior that is not doing what it is supposed to....weird.